# adding robots.txt file to nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, robots.txt

I am trying to add to my robots.txt file to stop indexing of unwanted WebPages. Most everything I have found deals with Cpanel/.htaccess - apache files. I use nginx as a proxy and would assume that I have to add it to the nginx.conf file. Where exactly would I add it? Below is my robots.txt as it now. I want to add.

```
Disallow: /retailer/inv/
```

Would this block all retailer inventory pages?

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /trade/
Disallow: /email/
Disallow: /saved/
Disallow: /print/
```

I am a novice but trying to learn on the go. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

robots.txt is checked by crawlers (including search engines), not the web server. Therefore it doesn't matter whether you're using Apache, Nginx or any other server; just so long as the file is present and publicly accessible.